# Use A Where In Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is a small snippet of my table structure (enough to show what I need to accomplish), and I can't get my syntax correct to achieve my end result.  What I am needing to accomplish is Show all records from #newdatabase (that's the easy part, a select * statement) AND if a record exists in #olddatabase ONLY exclude it if their is a null value for employeename.  I tried this query, but not the returned result set that I am after.

```
Select #newdatabase.orderID
FROM #newdatabase
LEFT JOIN #oldDatabase
ON #oldDatabase.orderID = #newdatabase.oldorderID
WHERE #oldDatabase.orderID IS NULL
AND #oldDatabase.employeename IS NULL
```

Here is my table structure

```
Create Table #oldDatabase
(
  orderID int,
  employeename varchar(100)
)

Create Table #newdatabase
(
  orderID int,
  oldorderID int
)

INSERT INTO #oldDatabase Values
(1, NULL),(2, NULL),(3, 'Mitch'),(4,'Sam'),(5, 'Streith'),(6, 'Azul'),(7,'Reta'),(8,'Frank'),(9,'Fred'),(10,'Nick'),
(11, NULL),(12, NULL),(13, NULL), (14, NULL), (15, NULL), (16, NULL)

INSERT INTO #newdatabase Values
(100,1), (101,2), (102,3), (103,4), (104,5), (105,6), (106,7), (107,8),     (108,9),
(109,10), (110,11), (111,12), (112,13), (113,Null),(114,Null), (115,NULL), (116,NULL),
(117,Null), (118,Null), (119,Null), (120,Null), (121,Null), (122,Null), (123,Null)
```

EDITORIAL - I want to see records in #newdatabase where either 1) they do not exist in #olddatabase OR 2) if they exist in #olddatabase and employeename is null.  Des that clarify?

Comment: What results would you like to get from the sample data you've posted? (I'm not sure I quite understand what you're looking for, because the SELECT you posted does not match your description.)

Comment: @KenWhite I want to see records in #newdatabase where either 1) they do not exist in #olddatabase OR 2) if they exist in #olddatabase and employeename is null.  Des that clarify?

Comment: Please [edit] your post, and show the *exact results* you expect from the sample data you posted (in a text table). Your SQL still doesn't match your description, and if you'll just simply post a table representing the results you'd like to get from your sample data, it would be clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several ways you can achieve this, I recommend the first:

```
    Select #newdatabase.orderID
      FROM #newdatabase
 LEFT JOIN #oldDatabase
        ON #oldDatabase.orderID = #newdatabase.oldorderID
       AND #oldDatabase.employeename IS NOT NULL
     WHERE #oldDatabase.orderID IS NULL
```

Or

```
    Select #newdatabase.orderID
      FROM #newdatabase
 LEFT JOIN #oldDatabase
        ON #oldDatabase.orderID = #newdatabase.oldorderID
     WHERE #oldDatabase.employeename IS NULL
```

Or

```
    Select #newdatabase.orderID
      FROM #newdatabase
     WHERE #newdatabase.orderID NOT IN
           ( SELECT #oldDatabase.orderID 
               FROM #oldDatabase
              WHERE #oldDatabase.employeename IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below.

```
(Select #newdatabase.orderID
FROM #newdatabase
EXCEPT
SELECT #oldDatabase.orderID
FROM #oldDatabase)
UNION
SELECT #oldDatabase.orderID
FROM #oldDatabase
AND #oldDatabase.employeename IS NULL
```

The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use the ALL keyword with UNION.([source](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp))